# How do I add an extra field to the commerce product entity and have it show on the product display?

Tags: 7, commerce

I am trying to add an extra field to commerce product and have it show on the corresponding product display node. So far I created the extra field and declared a theme function as shown below:

```
/*
 * Implements hook_field_extra_fields()
 */
function example_field_extra_fields() {
  $extra = array();

  foreach (commerce_product_types() as $type => $product_type) {
    $extra['commerce_product'][$type] = array(
      'display' => array(
        'bulk_savings' => array(
          'label' => t('Bulk Savings'),
          'description' => t('Bulk savings'),
          'theme' => 'example_bulk_savings',
          'weight' => 0,
        ),
      )
    );
  }
  return $extra;
}

/**
  * Implements hook_theme().
  */
function example_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'example_bulk_savings' => array(
      'variables' => array('bulk_savings' => NULL, 'label' => NULL, 'product' => NULL),
    ),
  );
}

/*
 * Bulk savings theme function.
 */
function theme_example_bulk_savings($variables) {
  $output = check_plain($variables['bulk_savings']);
  return $output;
}
```

The last step would be declaring the contents of the field and attaching it the commerce product entity. I tried using hook_entity_view(), but only the node object is available on the product display node. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you,

Paul